# Teradata : Complex case statement

Tags: if-statement, time-complexity, case, teradata

I have a emp_id with different statuses. Based on those status , I need to retrieve the values. For example,

**Employee Table**

```
Emp_id ********   Status1   ********   Status2**********desc********judgement     
******            ******
A1 ------------   Original ---------- Original---------fail--------pass
      
A1 ------------   Duplicate---------- Duplicate-------fail----------fail

B1 ------------   Original------------Original--------correct--------pass

B1 ------------   CORRECTION----------Original--------correct-----correct
```

**Expected output:**

```
Emp_id ********   Status1   ********   Status2***********FinalAnswer
******            ******
A1 ------------   Original ---------- Original-----------Pass
      
A1 ------------   Duplicate---------- Duplicate----------fail

B1 ------------   CORRECTION----------Original---------correct
```

There are 2 points here:

1. When for A1, if status1 and status2 are Original & duplicate, I need to see both records with the value coming from 'judgment' column.

2)When for B1, if status1 and status2 are Original & CORRECTION, I need to see only one record with the value coming from 'desc' column.

I did write a CASE but it is not working as expected.

```
select 


CASE ( when status1=trim('Original') and status2=trim('Original')  
      Or status1=trim('Duplicate') and status2=trim('Duplicate') ) then Judgment     

from employee;
```

Am seeing the below output from my case stmt which is not completely correct:

**Emp_id ******** Status1 ******** Status2***********FinalAnswer**

A1 ------------ Original ---------- Original-----------Pass

A1 ------------ Duplicate---------- Duplicate----------fail

When I'm trying to modify the case stmt with the B1 details... then am getting duplicates for the "Original" status from A1 .

Please help me.

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: Am getting below output:    Emp_id ********   Status1   ********   Status2***********FinalAnswer
    ******            ******
    A1 ------------   Original ---------- Original-----------Pass
          
    A1 ------------   Duplicate---------- Duplicate----------fail

Comment: Im not using any "Correction" related records.. because.. am getting duplicates.

Comment: You need to add more details: Is this logic based on individual rows or both rows? Are B1 & B2 the different emp_ids or just a typo?

Comment: my bad..  its B1.  typo

Comment: Please help me in solving this

Comment: What if there's only 1 row for an emp, or more than 2? What if there are multiple CORRECTION rows?

Comment: We can also have only one row for an employee and that one would be the first Original record.

Comment: Correction rows cane be max of 2. Based on the latest record considering the creation_date needs to be retrieved